# How to Set Fallback Images in Polymer

Tags: javascript, image, polymer

I am loading images dynamically based on item data.  Not all items have an image, however.  When scrolling through a `dom-repeat` I am getting a lot of `404 Not (Found)` error in DevTools.

How can I set a fallback image?

Is there a way to pre-fetch the route to see if it's valid before sending a get request so the log doesn't throw lots of errors?

```
<img id="img" src="[[item.src]]" onerror="dothis">
```

...

```
dothis() {
  console.log('do this');
  this.$.id.src = 'path/to/fallback.jpg';
}
```

This `onerror` function writes "Uncaught ReferenceError: dothis is not defined" to tho log.

Answer (score 1):

```
onerror="dothis"
```

Probably is not working because you're trying to bind a method of your `PolymerElement` to a normal HTML Event Attribute which is not aware of your component's context (it searches for a global identifier named `dothis`) unlike what happens with Polymer `on-*` custom element attributes which are not available in the native `img` element.

For your purpose you might consider using Polymer's `iron-image`: its `placeholder` property

> can be set to a URL (preferably a data-URI, for instant rendering) for an placeholder image

(from [iron-image documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-image/elements/iron-image)).

```
<iron-image
    preload
    placeholder="./loading.png">
</iron-image>
```

`preload` ensures that the placeholder image is displayed also in between `src` changes and in case of failure.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an event called `error-changed`
this will fire when the error property changes. So you can hook onto this and call a function that changes your src to a default image.
Take a look at the [iron-image documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-image/elements/iron-image)